# Another permutator

Tags: c++, strings, c++11, combinatorics

This is a solution to [this problem](http://www.cprogramming.com/challenges/permute.html). The problem statement:

> write a program to display all possible permutations of a given input
>   string--if the string contains duplicate characters, you may have
>   multiple repeated results. Input should be of the form
>
> permute *string*
>
> and output should be a word per line.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> permute(std::string s) {
    std::vector<std::string> retval;
    if (s.length() <= 1) {
        retval.push_back(s);
        return retval;
    } else {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
            std::rotate(s.begin(), s.begin() + 1, s.end());
            for (std::string permutation : permute(s.substr(1, std::string::npos))) {
                retval.push_back(s.substr(0,1).append(permutation));
            }
        }
        return retval;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::string toPermute;
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cout << "Please enter a word to permute:" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> toPermute;
    } else {
        toPermute = argv[1];
    }

    std::vector<std::string> result = permute(toPermute);

    std::cout << "Number of permutations: " << result.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::string(24, '=') << std::endl;

    for (std::string permutation : result) {
        std::cout << permutation << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at `std::next_permutation()` The number of permutations of a string is `factorial(string.size())`

Comment: Yes, `std::next_permutation` is in one of the answers already. I only included the number of permutations to be able to verify the algorithm generated the right number (by computing the factorial) so replacing that with the factorial function would sort of defeat the purpose. @LokiAstari

Answer (score 4):

- Technically, the code doesn't meet the requirements: displaying number of permutations is not requested. You may add an option to display it as well, but a *simple* invocation `permute string` shall display *only* the permutations.
- Returns from `permute`: a non-void function with no return at the very end may raise some eyebrows.

  Just extract `return retval;` out of `if/else` construct:

  ```
  if (s.length() <= 1) {
      retval.push_back(s);
  } else {
      ...
  }
  return retval;
  ```
- Algorithm has exponential time complexity. It is OK, because of the nature of task. It also requires exponential amount of memory, and *it* is not OK. You are not asked to *keep* all permutations, you just need to *display* them. And there *is* a solution with constant memory requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a loop to display the vector, you can just use iterators:

```
std::copy(result.begin(), result.end(),
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n");
```

(this requires both `<algorithm>` and `<iterator>`)

I've also used `\n` here since you really don't need to use `std::endl` in so many places.

Answer (score 2):

Your permutation work could really be simplified by using `std::next_permutation`** in `<algorithm>`.

```
void displayStringPermutations(std::string str, std::ostream& stream, const std::string& delim) {
   std::sort(std::begin(str), std::end(str));

   do {
      stream << str << delim;
   }
   while (std::next_permutation(std::begin(str), std::end(str)));
}
```

Adapting this to return a `std::vector<std::string>` of permutations or generalizing for any `Container::value_type` for re-usability pretty much takes the same form.

**`std::next_permutation` will return the next higher permutation. It is well within the definition of this problem as your problem stipulates that it "may have multiple repeated results" and not that it "should have multiple repeated results".

Comment: Thank you. If this was 'real' code I certainly should have used that, but the point of this exercise was to implement a permutation algorithm. Nonetheless, it's good to know it exists.

Comment: To be on-topic on CodeReview, your original post should be 'real' code.  With a [tag:c++11] tag and your use of `std::rotate`, I felt the response was appropriate and applicable for the purposes of CodeReview.

Comment: @Snowhawk04: I added that tag myself since the OP was using range-based `for` loops.